# Problem to add service principal permissions with terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm trying to add service principal Databricks managed on azure and put account level permissions with terraform like this:

[image]

**Error: cannot create mws permission assignment: Endpoint not found for /2.0/accounts/4f93b050-9cee-4668-8136-7937fe98f18e/workspaces/6491331033656740/permissionassignments/principals/187629890527464**

**terraform:**

```
provider "databricks" {
  azure_workspace_resource_id = azurerm_databricks_workspace.xxxxx_workspace.id
  host = azurerm_databricks_workspace.xxxxx_workspace.workspace_url
  auth_type = "azure-cli"
}

resource "azurerm_databricks_workspace" "xxxxx_workspace" {
  name                    = "ADM-Databricks-xxxx"
  resource_group_name     = var.resource_group_name
  location                = var.region
  sku                     = "premium"
  custom_parameters {
    storage_account_name = "admdatalakedevxxxxx${random_string.naming.result}"
    
  }
}

resource "databricks_service_principal" "principal" {
  display_name         = "databricks-adm"
  allow_cluster_create = true
  workspace_access = true
  databricks_sql_access = true
}

resource "databricks_group_member" "i-am-admin" {
  group_id  = data.databricks_group.admins.id
  member_id = databricks_service_principal.principal.id
}

resource "databricks_mws_permission_assignment" "add_admin_group" {
  workspace_id = azurerm_databricks_workspace.xxxxx_workspace.workspace_id
  principal_id = databricks_service_principal.principal.id
  permissions  = ["ADMIN"]
}
```